# withdrawing graduate admission application and reapplying to the same program

Tags: graduate-admissions

I have made some monumental mistakes in my application for graduate admission to a university in the US. I am thinking of withdrawing my application and then reapplying to the same program again. Will it harm my chance of getting full consideration?

I have submitted my application yesterday and the last date of application is December 01.

Thanks...

Comment: Without knowing more about what you did incorrectly it isn't easy to answer this question. I can't speak for all programs, but if someone had withdrawn this early in and then reapplied a bit later, when I was on an admissions committee for a masters program, I doubt we would have even noticed. the first application since that would have happened at an administrative level that never got to us.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your comments. By mistake, I have uploaded my CV twice, both in the place of CV and in the place of SOP.

Comment: That's a really minor issue. Email someone at the school (possibly the departmental secretary) and ask them to attach your SOP to the application. Little things like this happen all the time and aren't a big deal.

Answer (score 4):

Your comment suggests that this was a clerical error in an online submission.

You have time before the December deadline to find (email) someone at the school who should be able to tell you how to correct the error.

It's unlikely that anyone has looked at your application. The committee probably waits until all applicants are in to begin deciding on admission.